# reading a timestamp file and creating a directory structure depends upon the timestamp

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have log files for year's data , I want to read inside the log file and take the unix timestamp column and convert to human readable timestamp(not literally, only logically) . Depends on the timestamp .
I want to create a Time based directory structure Something like this ( 2017/05/20/13 ) (YYYY/MM/DD/HH) and copy those files to respective directory structure

```
LANG=C
if [[ -z "$1" ]]
  then
if [[ -p /dev/stdin ]]    # input from a pipe
  then
    read -r p
 else
    echo "No timestamp given." >&2
    exit
 fi
  else
p=$1
fi
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"}{$7=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$7)} {print}' 
sample.txt
```

this is the Log file sample output after the awk command , Now I want to create a folder depends on the date and hour . Something like this

```
Input 
counter.txt
28:-58:31147:28:0:0:2017-05-24 15:12:50:3064:0:0:0:103
28:-58:31147:28:0:0:2017-05-24 15:12:50:3064:0:0:0:102
21:-60:17086:28:0:0:2017-05-24 15:12:50:1384:0:0:0:102
10:-64:16651:28:0:0:2017-05-24 16:12:50:656:0:0:0:103
```

folder structure be like 
     [root@master 24-05-17]# ls -ltr | grep counter_
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 11974276 May 23 12:32 counter_25.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 17271141 May 23 13:32 counter_24.txt
     -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 16819152 May 23 14:32 counter_23.txt

output is like :

```
/2017/05/24/15 - in this folder , we have to seperate the input file and write 
counter_2017_05_24_15.txt 
28:-58:31147:28:0:0:2017-05-24 15:12:50:3064:0:0:0:103
28:-58:31147:28:0:0:2017-05-24 15:12:50:3064:0:0:0:102
21:-60:17086:28:0:0:2017-05-24 15:12:50:1384:0:0:0:102

/2017/05/24/16 in this folder , I want to write the remaining data in another 
new file and store seperately under the folder 
counter_2017_05_24_16.txt
10:-64:16651:28:0:0:2017-05-24 16:12:50:656:0:0:0:103
23:-66:33444:28:0:0:2017-05-24 16:12:50:656:0:0:0:103
10:-64:16651:28:0:0:2017-05-24 16:12:50:656:0:0:0:102
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi John, I have a timestamp like this 1495532564.This is unix format.The above program will convert into IST format but my question is I want to create a directory depends upon timestamp value. lets say 17-05-2017 means I want to create a dir like 17/05/2017.can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Do this:

```
strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Now you have a DD/MM/YYYY string, and can use it as part of a path.

Comment: okay sure.But how can I create a directory with the timestamp value??

Comment: @user3427653: I suggest `mkdir`.

Comment: I have a set of values .like 1/1/2015,1/1/2016,1/1/2017. I want to check the time stamp and creates a directory structure continuously. example I will run the shell script..It reads the timestamp and creates the directory according to the value.