# Extract Time stamp from a file and create a time stamp directory structure

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract the timestamp from the Text file(log file) and create a folder inside the folder dynamically based on the date and hour basis

```
Example file name : tag_data_2017_05_25_01_32_34.txt
file names : 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:56 tag_data_2017_05_25_01_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:56 tag_data_2017_05_25_02_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:56 tag_data_2017_05_25_03_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:56 tag_data_2017_05_25_04_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:57 tag_data_2017_05_25_05_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:57 tag_data_2017_05_25_06_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:57 tag_data_2017_05_25_07_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:57 tag_data_2017_05_25_08_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:57 tag_data_2017_05_25_09_32_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 May 25 18:57 tag_data_2017_05_25_10_32_34.txt
```

So I want to create a folder inside a folder /2017/05/25/01    (YYYY/DD/MM/HH)

```
shopt -s nullglob  
for filename in tag_data*.txt; do 
foldername=$(date +%Y%m%d%H)
    mkdir -p "$foldername"  
    mv "$filename" "$foldername"
    echo "$filename $foldername" ;
done
```

Output should be like :
`/2017/05/25/01/tag_data_2017_05_25_01_32_34.txt`

But the script above is just create a folder till `20170525` and moving all the files in a folder `20170525` ( do not want to copy in single folder ) want to copy in a hierarchy

the file `tag_data_2017_05_25_01_32_34` should go to folder `/2017/05/25/01/tag_data_2017_05_25_01_32_34.txt` , `/2017/05/25/01/tag_data_2017_05_25_02_32_34.txt` and goes on like that .

I'm a beginner to shell Script . Any leads or help would be appreciated .

Comment: Are you sure you want the current time for the folder, and not the time encoded in the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `date`, which gives you the current date, which may not necessarily be the date encoded in the file name.

```
for f in tag*.txt; do
  IFS=_ read _ _ year month day hour _ <<< "$f"
  directory="$year/$month/$day/$hour"
  mkdir -p "$directory" || exit 1  # Don't continue if this fails
  mv "$f" "$directory"
done
```

Comment: I have another problem regarding the same, If you can help that would be helpful a lot for me. Inside the tag_data_2017_05_25_01_32_34.txt , The data will be like this .
(start of the file )12:-60:33137:28:0:0:1495618970:2788:0:0:0:102
...
...
...
(end of the file ) 21:-46:20675:28:0:0:1495622570:2788:0:0:0:102
If you decode the Unix timestamp 

Output : date -d@1495618970
1495618970 - May 24 15:12:50 IST 2017
1495622570 - May 24 16:12:50 IST 2017
Now I want to read the files and Decode the unix timestamp and Split every hour data properly and create a folder structure .seemed tough

Comment: Please post a new question separately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176646/reading-a-timestamp-file-and-creating-a-directory-structure-depends-upon-the-tim

Please have a look . You canhelp i believe and seemed little tough . Thanks a lot